# In git, how can I create an 'isolate branch' (act just the same as master branch)?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and github. I've just created an  github page for my project, and I fetched the remote and found it just create another branch named "gh-pages" for me, which is great but strange enough when I see the history of that unique branch: it has a clean history, not relay on the master branch as I had thought, it just act as another isolate branch just like the master one, so I wonder how that 'isolate branch' be created, and what's the relationship between it and master one?

Following is the head part of the history of the two branches:

`* 2f436e7 - (HEAD, origin/gh-pages, gh-pages) init`

`*   a8f5635 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge pull request #13 from yqfang/editng`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github `gh-pages` is an orphan branch.

Orphan branch means that you have a clean branch without history.
you create it using the **`--orphan`** flag.

Once creating the orphan branch you get the latest commit content
(same as any other **`git checkout -b ...`** ) but without any history.

Comment: First time to hear the 'orphan branch', it's a nice thing. Can I just put it  the same role as the master branch ?